# How to send acknowledgement to a message to server from client when using gorilla-websockets in go?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I want to invoke HTTP endpoints at client-side using WebSockets. I am wrapping all required data like endpoint, payload, etc as a JSON and sending it to the client from server. 
Now, the client which is running in the private network will make rest call to HTTP endpoint which is enclosed in the message and will return the data to the server.

I am not able to figure out the way to send the acknowledgment to the server for a message.

Comment: Are you asking how to send a message from a client to a server on s websocket connection?  Is the client using the Gorilla package or something else?

Comment: I am able to send the msg from client->server and vice versa but how to send the acknowledgement that client or server has received the message.

Comment: Send an acknowledgment message just like any other message. What is the reason that you need to send acknowledgement messages separate from the HTTP requests and responses sent over the connection?

Comment: I want to invoke HTTP endpoints at client-side using WebSockets. I couldn't find any way to it. So, I am wrapping all required data like endpoint, payload, etc as a JSON and sending it to the client from server. Now, the client which is running in the private network will make rest call to HTTP endpoint which is enclosed in the message and will return the data to the server. So, this response will be packaged in acknowledgment which is sent to server and server can identify the exact response.

Comment: Assign a unique id to the request on the server, include that id in the request message, echo the id back to the server in the response message, server uses id to correlate response with request.

Comment: Yes, thought of that solution. BTW thanks a lot (y)

Comment: I was looking for another solution where I don't need to maintain such logics for filtering response in server.

Comment: It should take a few lines of code to implement the feature.